# Problems upgrading to EF 6.0. Missing EntityStoreSchemaGenerator

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We have some code that utilizes the EntityStoreSchemaGenerator to auto-generate an entity model from a database.The code is based on the EdmGen2 code from here:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EdmGen2/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4216

This has worked well in previous versions of the EntityFramework, However; in EF 6.0.1 the code no longer compiles.

It seems that the support for generating models on the fly has been removed in the latest EF version. Can anyone confirm this?

Is there an alternative solution to generate the model classes on the fly, from code, available in EF 6.0?

Comment: EntityStoreSchemaGenerator has not been moved to EF6. How did you use it before? Depending on what you did you might be able to continue to use the EntityStoreSchemaGenerator from EF5. You may want to consider up voting this work item: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1666